# Using PHP with CSS

Tags: php, css

As you can see I have some inline CSS to set gradients for different browser types, I'd like to put this in a CSS file...

The issue is, to generate the URL within the CSS background property I use a random number, generated using inline PHP.

This makes the page quite messy, is there a way to separate this out and achieve the same thing?

```
<div class="jumbotron hidden-xs hidden-sm " id="headerhome" style="background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(166, 195, 206, 0.5), 
     rgba(166, 195, 206, 0.5)),
        linear-gradient(
        to bottom,
        rgba(64, 64, 64, 0) 70%,
        rgba(77, 78, 94, 0.5) 80%
    ), url('img/home/hero-img/hero-img-<?php echo $rand ?>.jpg');

        background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(166, 195, 206, 0.5), 
     rgba(166, 195, 206, 0.5)),
        url('img/home/hero-img/hero-img-<?php echo $rand ?>.jpg');

        background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(166, 195, 206, 0.5), 
     rgba(166, 195, 206, 0.5)),
        url('img/home/hero-img/hero-img-<?php echo $rand ?>.jpg');

        background: -linear-gradient(rgba(166, 195, 206, 0.5), 
     rgba(166, 195, 206, 0.5)),
        url('img/home/hero-img/hero-img-<?php echo $rand ?>.jpg');

        background-blend-mode: multiply;">
```

Is it more worth going with the approach of having a style.php file?

Comment: Please don't do this.... You are not always going to maintain this piece of code and you are not always going to develop alone. That being an ugly solution means that it is not the only one, there is always a cleaner solution (like change the image when serving it from the server that will still be better). As for @Michael_B honestly, this needs to stop - please - have you looked at PHP after PHP3, seriously do so...

Comment: So you want the gradient to be the same, but the jpg to be random? Do you happen to be using Sass?

Comment: Exactly, but I am currently not using Sass, I really do need to get a handle on pre processed CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of integration with HTML is precisely what PHP is designed for, among other things.

Of course, this creates more complex ("messy") code, but that's not necessarily a bad thing. Indeed, complexity is the natural result of layering code.

Comment: So essentially it isn't necessarily bad to do something like this as long as the developer (me) can maintain it?

Comment: Look under the hood of any major website (ctrl-u on windows). Things get pretty complex, and you can't even see the php. Think in terms of writing clean, valid and semantic code. If it can remain simple that's even better, but it's not essential.

Comment: And to make your code easier to maintain use comments. Seriously, comment, comment, comment. Leaving explanations will make things so much easier when years from now you, or someone helping you, needs to review and revise.